# HIde report in print menu based on state in odoo12

Tags: report, odoo, qweb, odoo-12

Need to hide qweb report based on state in odoo12 that is report must be available only in done state

```
<report
        id="action_report_gate_pass"
        model="bi.gate.pass"
        string="Gate Pass"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        name="bi_gate_pass.report_gate_pass"
        file="bi_gate_pass.report_gate_pass"
    />
```

Any way to add attribute or domain to report action

Comment: Restrict the report to a specific group.

Comment: he asked based in state, so add attrs in the end of the button print, simple as it is

Comment: @Navi He asked to do it in the report action and I made just  a suggestion

Comment: @Navi could you please write the script for this please? thanks